# Docker pulling windows image - failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1

Tags: docker, dockerfile, boot2docker, docker-machine

I'm using Windows 10 and I read from the internet that this issue is due to Antivirus. My corporate did not allow us to uninstall SEP since this is a strict policy.
May i know if we have already solution for this? Aside from uninstalling SEP Antivirus? Thanks!.

PS C:\FSD\Docker\Trial1> docker build -t lea/leatest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM microsoft/nanoserver
latest: Pulling from microsoft/nanoserver
bce2fbc256ea: Extracting [==================================================>]  252.7MB/252.7MB
6a43ac69611f: Download complete
***failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilte
r\17dec96c462c649daaa310f1ba046392f777090a6be78273a4b5002f94665d06\UtilityVM: The process cannot access the file because
 it is being used by another process.***

Answer (score 2):

Other customers with SEP have seen this issue, although there are also other causes besides AV software.

Do you have permission on your machine to create folder exclusions in SEP?

See the workaround proposed by aphophas in [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/355):

"I was able to get around this by just adding a folder exclusion for "C:\ProgramData\docker" in SEP on my box. Once I did that, the temp file being locked was released, and I was able to successfully pull, extract and view the image on my box. "

Comment: Thanks Myles. I have already tried to add "C:\ProgramData\Docker" in my SEP but still not fixed.

Comment: Thanks Myles. I have already tried to add "C:\ProgramData\Docker" in my SEP but still not fixed. In SEP i did this - Change Settings -> Exceptions -> Configure Settings -> Add -> Sonar Exception -> Folder -> indicate "C:\ProgramData\Docker" , include subfolders then click OK. The same step is made by adding Security Risk Folder Exception. So with that i have 2 entries User-Defined Exceptions (Security Risk Scans; All Scans and SONAR). Please let me know if i made it correctly. Or may i know how did you add yours in SEP. By the way i used SEP 12.1 version.

Comment: I don't have a machine with SEP to reproduce the issue.  If it's still not working, I would speak with your IT about a workaround that's acceptable to them.  We're reaching out to Symantec and other AV providers to make this work better in the future.  Sorry I can't be more help!

Comment: Luckily, our IT allowed me to upgrade my machine from SEP 12.1 to 14 and this fixed the issue. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Excellent!  Upgrading when possible is usually the best option.  We work with the AV folks to create fixes.  We try to backport any serious fixes to old versions of the container and Windows software.  Some AV companies will also do this, some prefer customers to upgrade.  If you tag any further issues with "docker-for-windows" someone on our team will help.  Cheers

Comment: i'm having this exact same problem with Symantec Endpoint Protection Cloud. The problem with your suggestion is that I am the administrator for Symantec and the domain and I cannot figure this out. I added C:\ProgramData\Docker as an exclusion folder in the cloud dashboard. I even temporarily turned off Auto-Protect and Sonar and I'm still getting this. error. Do not get this error on a PC that doesn't have Symantec.

Comment: going to amend this. my error is almost the same but slightly different
PS> docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer
...
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: time="2017-05-25T15:10:40-04:00" level=error msg="hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x20) layerId=\\\\?\\C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\fe57b489717bdf9029640ec179a8f5dde6d6db6a17b356b15e151f146f031cb1 flavour=1 folder=C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP\\hcs574834151"

Comment: @Zack Is SEP Cloud SaaS, i.e. always runs the latest version?  Or do you buy a particular version?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to update SEP from 12 to 14 and it works without any specific settings. While with the 12, I tried every workaround without any success.
Window 10 (15063.483), Docker 17.06.1.